# Changing the value of scaleX on a health bar when objects collide

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, game-physics

I have been trying loads of different ways to make my health bar scaleX increase by 25% incrementally when it hits targets.

So far the closest I've come is with else if statements. The problem is actionscript runs through the else if statements and doesn't stop, it does all of the calculations and makes my health bar full every time I hit something. I understand why this is happening (the else if statements are becoming true as AS3 runs through them) but I don't know how to stop it.
Any help is appreciated

```
var health:Number = 0;
var fullHealth:Number = 100;

healthBar.scaleX = health / fullHealth;

//collision

    if(dog_mc.hitTestObject(deadRat_mc)){
    deadRat_mc.visible=false;

      if (healthBar.scaleX==0){
         healthBar.scaleX =+.25;

        }
        else if (healthBar.scaleX==.25){
            healthBar.scaleX =+.50;
        }
        else if (healthBar.scaleX==.50){
            healthBar.scaleX =+.75;
        }
        else if (healthBar.scaleX==.75){
            healthBar.scaleX =+1;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use math, I'm guessing you copied that code somewhere but you don't know how to use it, health is meant to control the level of the health bar:

```
var health:Number = 0;
var fullHealth:Number = 100;
healthBar.scaleX = health / fullHealth;
if(dog_mc.hitTestObject(deadRat_mc))
{
    health += 25;
}
```

That's all you need.

Comment: I tired a lot of ways. Your post was the first and most obvious thing I tried, it didn't accomplish any change in the scale, it just stays at 0.

Comment: Don't you need to first increase the health and set the scalex after that?

Comment: the order is irrelevant as long as this code runs in an enter frame or timer.